# Error in calling function from another swiftUI file

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swift and i am currently stuck, where i can't seem to figure out what is causing the error.
I want to call a swiftUI file that is taking information from a JSON decoder(I only want one JSON object not a list), and adding that file to main body off the swiftUI file.

It has 2 error currently "Instance member 'songs' cannot be used on type 'ModelData'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"
and "Cannot convert value of type '[mainSupport]' to expected argument type 'mainSupport'
"
CODE BELOW

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MainSupport: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable{
    var id: Int
    var song: String
    var artist: String
    private var img: String

    var image: Image {
        Image(img)
    }    
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var songs: [MainSupport] = load("song.json")
}

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

^^JSON decoder

```
import SwiftUI

struct Playback_friend: View {
    var sodata: mainSupport
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(Sodata.song).font(.title3).fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(Sodata.Artist).fontWeight(.light)
            }
            Image(systemName: "waveform").font(.system(size: 40))
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct Playback_friend_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var songs = ModelData().songs
    static var previews: some View {
        Playback_friend(sodata: Songs[0])
    }
}
```

^^file i want to call

```
import SwiftUI
struct XustomColor {
    static let lead = Color("lead")
    static let up_grad = Color("upGrad")
    static let low_grad = Color("lowGrad")
    // Add more here...
}
struct BackView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    static var songs = ModelData().songs
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [XustomColor.up_grad, XustomColor.low_grad]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
            HStack {    
                VStack{
                    HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                        VStack{
                            ProfilePic(image: Image("proPic"))
                                .padding(.leading)
                            Text("Suniya")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .lineLimit(nil)
                                .padding(.leading)
                        }
                        Playback_friend(Sodata: ModelData.songs)

                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 40.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
                    .background(
                        CustomColor.lead
                            .cornerRadius(60)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                                CustomColor.lead
                                    .frame(height: 10)
                            }
                    )
                    .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], -40)
                            
                        
                    Spacer()
                        
                    List(modelData.songs) { songs in 
                        SongRows(soData: songs)         
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .listRowBackground(XustomColor.lead)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom,230)
                    .listRowBackground(XustomColor.up_grad)
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal).padding(.top,50)
                Spacer()              
            }
        }.frame(height: 820).padding(.top,30).ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct backView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var Songs=ModelData().songs
    static var previews: some View {
        backView().environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

^^file i want to call to

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "song": "Wake me up when Semtember ends",
        "Artist": "Green Day",
        "img": "wake_me_up_when_september_ends"
        
    
    },
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "song": "drivers license",
        "Artist": "Olivia Rodrigo",
        "img": "drivers_license"
        
    },
    {
        "id": 1003,
        "song": "money tree",
        "Artist": "Kendrick Lamar",
        "img": "money_tree"
        
    },
    {
        "id": 1004,
        "song": "california girls",
        "Artist": "katy perry",
        "img": "california_girls"
        
    },
]
```

JSON file as asked by @son

Comment: can you show the JSON file? btw, following by swift coding convention, struct type should start with uppercase.

Comment: Please make sure you follow Swift convention of naming types with `UpperCase` and variables with `lowerCase`. It's very confusing to read otherwise.

Comment: You are talking about files but Swift is about types (struct, class etc) and instances, objects, of those types and by looking at your code I don't think you have grasped this concept since you are trying to get values from a type when you should get it from an object. May I suggest you read [this chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/classesandstructures) from the Swift Programming Language book